# Selenium test coverage for .net (C# and VB)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, selenium, code-coverage

What I'm looking for is a way to show me code coverage from my Selenium tests. At this point in time, I'm not sure if this is possible since the tests just load up an instance of a browser.

From the research I have done, it seems like all the tools that can accomplish this do code coverage for JAVA exclusively, which doesn't help me out since my codebase is a mixture of C# and VB.

I looked at the paid version of NCover (the trial), but cannot get NCover to attach to anything. After doing more reading, from my understanding NCover is looking for a .net application, so it can't grab on to a web browser.

The reason I am interested in the code coverage is because I am building out Selenium tests for teams here and wanted to see a trend over time to see how things are improving.

If anyone can point me in the direction of something to help me out I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have found the answer, NCover can do this as it will attach itself to the IIS w3wp.

See the documentation here: [Documentation](http://www.ncover.com/support/docs/v3/how-to/code-coverage-of-asp-net-applications-on-iis)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I looked over the documentation and I see 2 things blocking my path. The first is that I am using the WebDriver, not Selenium RC (sorry for not specifying.) And second, that documentation calls for a program called MicroFind installed and running inside IIS. My search results for MicroFind only lead me to the documentation you provided.

Comment: WebDriver is a newer version of the selenium implementation. If you read it you should be able to translate it into WebDriver. I will take a look at MicroFind first thing tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, things are working properly now. My tests were hitting the test environment, which meant there was no w3wp process for NCover to attach to. I needed to change that to run in dev so NCover could grab onto my w3wp process, which required adding a few domains to my IIS.

Comment: Awesome! If I helped please feel free to mark as answer and up vote.